# How can I return one element from a large, multi-dimensional JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a huge array that I only need to return one particular value from, but I don't know how to access it. I only included a small section of it below. The part that I need to be able to access is at the very end, right before the function ("mag_id"). Usually, I can use some form of dot notation to transverse thru an array, but I haven't been able to find something that works in this case for some reason.

The full example is on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/xuzavud/edit?js,console,output

```
var array1=[{
    "AddtionalFields": [{
        "Name": "short_description",
        "Type": 4,
        "Value": "Made with a synthetic polymer..."
        },
        {
            "Name": "minimal_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "special_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "type_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "configurable"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Price",
            "Type": 7,
            "Value": "7.99"
        },
        {
            "Name": "absorbency_sort_integer_tf",
            "Type": 5,
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "cost",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "giftcard_amounts",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "ACDesc",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "#E015 E015 3536P,3536,3537P,3537,3538P,3538 E015"
        },
        {
            "Name": "mag_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "12517"
        }
        ]
    }
]

function search(nameKey, myArray){
  for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
        return myArray[i];
    }
 }
}

var resultObject = search("mag_id", array1);

console.log(resultObject);
```

Comment: What mulit-dimensional array? `array1` has only one dimension, and its single element is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your extract the item as below

```
var array1 = [
{"AddtionalFields":
[
{"Name":"short_description",
"Type":4,
"Value":"Made with a synthetic polymer, so they are less likely to cause irritation and allergic reactions.  The heavy-duty iris blue nitrile gloves feature textured fingers for improved grip. They meet or exceed ASTM D6319 and ASTM D6124 standards."},
{"Name":"minimal_price",
"Type":9,
"Value":""},
{"Name":"special_price",
"Type":9,
"Value":""},
{"Name":"type_id",
"Type":9,
"Value":"configurable"},
{"Name":"Price",
"Type":7,
"Value":"7.99"},
{"Name":"absorbency_sort_integer_tf",
"Type":5,
"Value":"0"},
{"Name":"cost",
"Type":9,
"Value":""},
{"Name":"giftcard_amounts",
"Type":9,
"Value":""},
{"Name":"ACDesc",
"Type":9,
"Value":"#E015 E015 3536P,3536,3537P,3537,3538P,3538 E015"},
{"Name":"mag_id",
"Type":9,
"Value":"12517"}] } ];

const _item = array1[0].AddtionalFields.find((el)=>{
return el.Name == 'mag_id'
})

console.log(_item)
```

Comment: @Ipradhap Thanks for your help. That was exactly what I needed to get the right information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your array it is not multidimensional and has one object element. First you need to extract the keys and values of your object. Then you get the length, loop and filter through it. The code below returns the object where your keyword was found. You can also view more information [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/) about looping through objects. Hope this helps.

```
    var obj=[{
        "AddtionalFields": [{
            "Name": "short_description",
            "Type": 4,
            "Value": "Made with a synthetic polymer..."
        },
        {
            "Name": "minimal_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "special_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "type_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "configurable"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Price",
            "Type": 7,
            "Value": "7.99"
        },
        {
            "Name": "absorbency_sort_integer_tf",
            "Type": 5,
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "cost",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "giftcard_amounts",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "ACDesc",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "#E015 E015 3536P,3536,3537P,3537,3538P,3538 E015"
        },
        {
            "Name": "mag_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "12517"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]

    function search(nameKey, myArray){

        //Extract values from object
        var values = Object.values(myArray); 

        //loop through the object and filter the keyword
        for(var x of values){
            for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(x.AddtionalFields).length; i++){
                if(x.AddtionalFields[i].Name == nameKey || x.AddtionalFields[i].Type == nameKey || x.AddtionalFields[i].Value == nameKey){
                    return x.AddtionalFields[i];
                }
            }
        }

    }

    var resultObject = search("#E015 E015 3536P,3536,3537P,3537,3538P,3538 E015", obj);

    console.log(resultObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, but just didn't quite get the structure. Basically, this:

```
array1[0].AddtionalFields
```

Gets you to the array you want to search.

I've commented the code below so you can see what is going on:

- `array1` is an array with a *single element*
- Access that element with array notation `[0]` (meaning the first element)
- Now, `array[0]` refers to a single *Object* with a *single property* `AddtionalFields` (note the spelling error)
- That object contains thearray you seem to want to search
- JavaScript has the really coolfunction for arrays called filter

  - filter docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
var array1=[{
    "AddtionalFields": [{
        "Name": "short_description",
        "Type": 4,
        "Value": "Made with a synthetic polymer..."
        },
        {
            "Name": "minimal_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "special_price",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "type_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "configurable"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Price",
            "Type": 7,
            "Value": "7.99"
        },
        {
            "Name": "absorbency_sort_integer_tf",
            "Type": 5,
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "cost",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "giftcard_amounts",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "ACDesc",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "#E015 E015 3536P,3536,3537P,3537,3538P,3538 E015"
        },
        {
            "Name": "mag_id",
            "Type": 9,
            "Value": "12517"
        }
        ]
    }
]

// array1 is an array with a single element
// Access that element with array notation [0] (meaning the first element)
// Now, array[0] refers to a single Object with a single property AddtionalFields (note the spelling error)
// That object contains the array you seem to want to search
// JavaScript has the really cool function for arrays called filter - use it like this:
let result = array1[0].AddtionalFields.filter(element=>element.Name === "mag_id");
console.log(result);
```